# Azure api management git repository media files

Tags: azure-api-management

I have created azure api management instance with some media files and styles in it. I cloned this as git repository. In my local repo, I'm not able to find the media files which I have uploaded in the main portal.

Is there any specific folder to check this content locally? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official doc for configuration using git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git#file-and-folder-structure-reference-of-local-git-repository), *developer portal entities other than styles* are not contained in the git repository.

**Note** that the original developer portal is now deprecated. The [new developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal) comes with a more modern approach and can be self-hosted, allowing you to have complete control of the site contents and limitless extensibility.